# Repeated records when doing a JOIN in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have the `questions` table:

```
id, title, quiz_id
```

and the `quiz_answers` table:

```
id, question_id, user_id, answer
```

With the following query I get the answers for a certain quiz for two users:

```
SELECT qa.id, qa.question_id as "questionId", qa.user_id as "userId",
            qa.answer, qa.created_at as "createdAt"
      FROM quiz_answers AS qa
      JOIN questions AS qst ON qst.quiz_id = 3
      WHERE qa.user_id IN ('foo', 'bar')
      GROUP BY "questionId", qa.id;
```

I also want to add the question title to each returned row. The problem is that when I add it to the `SELECT`'ed columns, I also need to either aggregate it or add it to the `GROUP BY` clause. And both of these actions result in having the wrong result: duplicate records.

I tried to think of how to do this with a nested `SELECT` query on the `questions` table, instead of using a `JOIN`, but to no avail.

Comment: `quiz_id` is in the `questions` table. It's a foreign key to another table.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your join clause is not correct.
You should

- JOIN on `qa.question_id=qst.id`
- add the `qst.quiz_id = 3` in the WHERE clause